# How can 2 applications on the same websphere server see each others static content?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere

We have one websphere server with multiple applications running on it. They're all running on separate profiles, but they are somehow able to access each others static content.

For example, the following URLs both return images...

```
http://firstapp.com/images/image.gif
http://secondapp.com/images/image.gif
```

...when the image only exists in the project of the first app! The domains each point to different IPs, which are then routed to different ports on the server.

We can't see anything obvious in the websphere configuration files. Anyone seen this before? We'd appreciate any help!

**UPDATE: I won't have access to troubleshoot or even analyze the server for about a month, unfortunately. I'm pretty sure the problem is in the websphere apache plugin configuration.**

Answer (score 0):

I need additional inputs to help you.

First thing, is images a webapp context root?

From the URL i am assuming that is the case.

I am also assuming that you are fronting the WAS with a web server as you are not specifying the port number of the WAS Server instances.

WHat is firstapp.com and secondapp.com (is that a host name). I want to ascertain that you are not swallowing the  context root when you provided these URLs.

If the Web Server plugin is used (which is the case if you are accessing via port 80 as seen by the URL), whom does it route the request to?

I guess i will be able to help you once i have your inputs on the above.

Manglu

Answer (score 0):

Do you have content fronted up by IBM Apache or similar? That's what I'd look at in the first instance.

Comment: Yes, though I won't have access to troubleshoot or even analyze the server for about a month, unfortunately. I'm pretty sure the problem is in the websphere apache plugin configuration.